# Update Parameter Value in State

Tags: reactjs

how do I update a parameter value in a string? I have a initial state named historyURL:'search?keyword=[keyword]&subject=[subject]'. I would like to update state value of [keyword] and [subject] later in event handlers. Is this possible in reactjs?

```
state={historyurl:'search?keyword=[keyword]&subject=[subject]',
       keyword:'',
       subject:''
}
onSubjectChange(subject)=>{
    setState({subject:subject,
    historyurl:'search?keyword='+this.state.keyword+'&subject='+subject});
  }
onKeywordInput(keyword)=>{
    setState({keyword:keyword,
             historyurl:'search?keyword='+keyword+'&subject="+this.state.subject});
}
```

Comment: I think, no need to save `historyurl` in react state.  All parameters have been saved in state，so it can be obtained by calculation in anywhere.

Comment: HistoryURL is something you should calculate when you need it, there is no point in making it a part of state when it is derived directly from keyword and subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript itself has nothing built-in for handling query string parameters

Code running in a (modern) browser you can use the [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) (which is part of the APIs provided by browsers to JS):

```js
var url_string = "http://" + "search?keyword=[keyword]&subject=[subject]"; 
var url = new URL(url_string);
var keyword = url.searchParams.get("keyword");
console.log(keyword);

// set value
url.searchParams.set("keyword", "[new keyword]");
keyword = url.searchParams.get("keyword");
console.log(keyword);
```

In your case, maybe you can create a function called `updateParam(url, key, value)` using that method above and update the state

```
onKeywordInput(keyword)=>{
   this.setState(prevState => ({
      keyword: keyword,
      historyurl: updateParam(prevState.historyurl, 'keyword', keyword)
   }));
}
```

```js
function updateParam(urlParam, key, value) {
  var url = new URL("http://" + urlParam);
  url.searchParams.set(key, value);
  return url.toString().slice(7); // remove "http://"
}

console.log(updateParam("search?keyword=keyword&subject=subject", "keyword", "newKeyword"))
```